# How to show SnackBar in class

Tags: flutter, dart

i want call snack bar in this class on error method :

```
 class serverRequest {
  String _Url = "*****";

 Future<String> getRequest(String Url, Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
  String BaseUrl = _Url + Url;
  var dio = Dio();
  print(BaseUrl.toString());
  dio.interceptors
    .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
  print("REQUEST[${options?.method}] => PATH: ${options?.path}");
  return options; //continue
  }, onResponse: (Response response) async {
  print(
      "RESPONSE[${response?.statusCode}] => PATH: ${response?.request?.path}");
  return response; // continue
  }, onError: (DioError err) async {
  print("ERROR[${err.toString()}] => PATH: ${err?.request?.path}");

  if (err.response.statusCode == 403) {
    // i want call snack bar here

  }
  return err; //continue
  }));
  Response response = await dio.post(BaseUrl, queryParameters: map);

  print(response.toString());
  return response.toString();
  }

  dynamic requestInterceptor(RequestOptions options) async {
  return options;
  }
```

this serverRequest class call in some pages for request and i want when have server error show snack bar in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an extra argument to the  ```getRequest`` method like so

```
 class serverRequest {
  String _Url = "*****";

 Future<String> getRequest(String Url, Map<String, dynamic> map, Function onError) async {
 //// 

  if (err.response.statusCode == 403) {
    // i want call snack bar here
    onError(statusCode);
 }
```

and when your calling this function in your widget, you can pass this

```
Function showErrorSnackBar(errorCode) {
   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(

    )
   )
}

/// where you call it, pass this function 

MaterialButton(
 // other props
  onPressed: () {
     serverRequest().getRequest(x,y, showErrorSnackBar)

  }
)
```

Comment: no worrres, please consider to upvote if the answer helped you. Thanks and Happy coding!